# How to write unit test case for due date validation ? How to unit test DateField or DateTimeField validation?

Tags: django, unit-testing, validation, django-models, django-rest-framework

Here main question is that how to write unittest cases for due date validation with DateField or DateTimeField we can do it through multiple methods & i will answer you those methods

So basically in `models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ValidationError

class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    desc = models.TextField(blank=True)
    time_stamp = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    due_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    # logic for due_date
    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
    
        if self.due_date < self.time_stamp:
            raise ValidationError("Due date must be greater than current date")
```

I am expecting to test this `clean()` validation method, in case when due date is less then `start_date` or `time_stamp` it should through `ValidationError`

Answer (score -1):

First Method : you can do it like this `test_model.py`

```
from django.test import TestCase
from Api.models import *
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def test_due_date_validation(self):
        task = Task.objects.create(title="Task Name", desc="Description", due_date="2023-12-16")
        self.assertRaises(ValidationError, task.full_clean)
```

Second Method : you can try also like this in `test_model.py` but sometimes its not work you

```
def test_due_date_validation(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
            Task.objects.create(title="Task Name", desc="Description", due_date="2023-12-16")
```